# Thin line of whitespace on between transformed parent and its' child

Tags: css

I've got a div with the same background-color as the parent divs' border-color. What I would like is for the parent div and the div with the background-color to align perfectly, but what I get is a thin line of whitespace between the parent and the child.

[image]

The parent div has is rotated inwards if that helps.

**Parent:**

```
border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
border-left: .5rem solid #222;
border-right: .5rem solid #222;
border-top: .5rem solid #222;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transform: perspective( 1200px ) rotateX( 20deg );
   -moz-transform: perspective( 1200px ) rotateX( 20deg );
        transform: perspective( 1200px ) rotateX( 20deg );
```

**Child:**

```
float: left;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #F2C3CC;
position: relative;
```

I hope the picture I provided is clear enough for you to see the whitespace that occurs between the border and the dark "DEMO" div.

I'm using OS X 10.9.5 along with Chrome 37.0.2062.124 if that would matter for this question.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0stcevw/)

Comment: The effect in the jsfiddle is [rather different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rvqrY.png) for me in Chrome latest on Windows 8.

Comment: it still shows the same lines @Jeroen only a little bit less..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused because of the gap between the border and background? My solution would be to create 2 child div's, one for the top, and one for the bottom, like here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0stcevw/2/)

```css
.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #222;
    border: .5rem solid #222;
    border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 1200px ) rotateX( 20deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective( 1200px ) rotateX( 20deg );
    transform: perspective( 1200px ) rotateX( 20deg );
    
}

.inner {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.innersecond{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">Lorem</div>
    <div class="innersecond">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

[edit] this fixed it for me, chrome 37 on windows 7

Comment: Cannot believe I didn't think of putting the background-color on the parent. Worked very well, thanks a lot!